# Getting the Auth Token with Ember-Auth

Tags: authentication, ember.js

I'm using Ember.js in conjunction with Ember-Auth. While uploading files via Jquery-File-Upload, I need to send the authenticity token through the headers. I'm approaching this like so:

```
didInsertElement: ->
  $('#image_upload').fileupload
    headers:
      'X-CSRF-Token': Whistlr.Auth.authToken
```

Unfortunately, `Whistlr.Auth.authToken` is undefined. I'm not even sure this is where Ember-Auth stores the auth token, though it seems like a likely candidate. Similarly, other attributes are undefined, such as `user` and `userId`. Aside from this, Ember-Auth seems to work fine, and it sends the auth token with every request. It's only when trying to manually retrieve it that I have this problem. Any advice as to what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know `Ember-Auth`, but to access properties in objects.
You have to use the `get` method.

```
Whistlr.Auth.get('authToken')
```

I hope it helps.